# Cross join of two tables

Tags: join, outer-join, kdb

I have two tables `x` and `y`. I want to join on column `b` such that I get `z` in output.

```
x:([a:1 2 1 3]; b:`a`a`b`b)
q) a | b
   -----
   1 | a
   2 | a
   1 | b
   3 | b

y:([b:`a`a`a`b]; c:7 8 9 10)
q) b |  c
   ------
   a |  7
   a |  8
   a |  9
   b | 10
```

Desired output:

```
q) a |  b |  c
   -----------
   1 |  a |  7
   1 |  a |  8
   1 |  a |  9
   2 |  a |  7
   2 |  a |  8
   2 |  a |  9
   1 |  b | 10
   3 |  b | 10
```

Is this some sort of cross join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [equi join (ej)](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/ej/) will produce the result you want:

```
q)ej[`b;x;y]
```